# Pandas dataframe - get column index for minimum value in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to get the column index for the lowest value in a row. For example, I have the dataframe

```
              0            1        Min. dist
0    765.180690   672.136265        672.136265            
1    512.437288   542.701564        512.437288
```

and need the following output

```
              0            1        Min. dist       ColumnID
0    765.180690   672.136265        672.136265             1       
1    512.437288   542.701564        512.437288             0
```

I've gotten the `Min. dist` column by using the code `df['Min. dist'] = df.min(axis=1)`

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `idxmin` :

```
df['ColumnID']=df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks!